# Pushing up two modified and committed GIT clones

Tags: git, version-control

I'm learning Git. I created 3 folders `e:\temp\repo remote`, `e:\temp\repo local 1` and `e:\temp\repo local 2`. I want to do the following things:

On folder `e:\temp\repo remote`:

```
git init --bash
```

On folder `e:\temp\repo local 1`:

```
git clone "e:\temp\repo remote" "e:\temp\repo local 1"
```

On folder `e:\temp\repo local 2`:

```
git clone "e:\temp\repo remote" "e:\temp\repo local 2"
```

Copy the file `file1.txt` into the `e:\temp\repo local 1\dir1` folder.
Copy the file `file2.txt` into the `e:\temp\repo local 2\dir2` folder.

On folder `e:\temp\repo local 1`

```
git add *
git commit -m "dir1\file1.txt created"
git push
```

On folder `e:\temp\repo local 2`

```
git add *
git commit -m "dir2\file2.txt created"
```

When I want to push the local 2 repo into the remote one, it fails with the following message:

```
To E:\temp\repo remote
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'E:\temp\repo remote'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."
```

I follow the instructions and call pull in repo local 2:

```
$ git pull
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From E:\temp\repo remote
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Or

```
$ git pull "e:\temp\repo remote"
From e:\temp\repo remote
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

But why are there unrelated histories?

How should I merge the changes of the second user into the remote repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are unrelated because the original repository never contained any history. `git init --bare` creates an empty (bare) repository without any history. There is not a single commit and not a single branch.

If you clone that empty repository, you get another empty repository, again without a commit and without a branch. So by doing that twice, you get two empty repositories that do not share anything except their remote.

Then, once you commit something in those local repositories, you are creating the first “root commit”. That root commit is then set as the starting point for that repository.

Since you do that in both repositories, you end up with two different root commits. These are not compatible to each other since they don’t share any history (they both are the root of their respective repository).

In order to avoid this, your repository should start with a root commit already. So just push a branch with at least one commit to the repository first before creating those clones. Then, the interaction using `pull` will work properly since Git will figure out that they share some history (at least the root commit).

Comment: Is the "master" not a branch?

Comment: Yes, but until you create the very first commit, even that branch does not actually exist. Git is in an intermediary state until you create the first commit.

Comment: Then what commands should I dispatch before the clone ones? (on the remote repository)

Comment: It is enough to only clone the second repository after pushing from the first. That way, the second will be initialized properly with a history.

Comment: After that can I clone the repos parallel? I want to try this case.

Comment: Yes, you can clone the repository as often as you want with their histories being compatible once the origin repository has any history. So yeah, once you pushed something from *any* clone, new clones will work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and usefull answers poke!